# telegram bot на java, отправка сообщений по расписанию

Tags: java, ооп, telegrambots

Пишу бота, используя библиотеку:

```
<groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
<artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0</version>
```

Хочу отправлять себе сообщения по расписанию, к примеру каждый час, для этого пользуюсь `ScheduledExecutorService`, в итоге получил такую структуру (код сильно урезан, но картину передать должен):

Класс `Main`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App bot = new App();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi;
        try {
            telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ParsingExchange(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
         execute(sendMessageController.createMessage(update, "Текст"));
    }
}
```

Класс `ParsingExchange` c методом `run`:

```java
public class ParsingExchange {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList();
        users.add("какие-то данные")
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что для отправки сообщения мне надо в `run` вызвать `execute`, а он есть только в классе `Main` (наследование от класса из библиотеки). И я не могу понять, как я должен вызвать `execute` из `run`, ведь они должны находиться в разных классах.

P.S. метод run - обязательно переопределяемый метод в ScheduledExecutorService, этот метод и будет вызываться и выполняться по моему заданному графику.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, иллюстрирующий проблему, чтобы вам было проще помочь.

Comment: @Vestalt дополнил, надеюсь так понятней.

Comment: То есть вам нужно вызвать метод `run` в методе `onUpdateReceived`? Или вызвать `execute` в `run`?

Comment: @Vestalt ```execute``` в ```run```

Comment: Как идея, можно сделать класс `ParsingExchange` внутренним в `Main`, тогда это будут разные классы, но у первого будет доступ к методам второго. Так даже будет лучше с точки зрения логики.

Comment: @Vestalt понимаю, но у меня логика в ```ParsingExchange ``` на самом деле не маленькая, которая со временем может разрастаться, и это получится каша. Возможно надо искать другую реализацию расписания, просто мне казалось, что это такая базовая проблема, я удивлен, что не смог легко загуглить ее. Уверен, что я не первый кто придумал отправлять в телеграме сообщения по таймингу.

Comment: @Vlad, добавьте в ваш вопрос уточнение, от каких классов наследуется класс `App`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в класс `ParsingExchange` поле с типом `App` и инициализируйте его в конструкторе.

Тогда в методе `run` вы сможете вызывать метод `execute` для работы с ботом:

```java
public class ParsingExchange implements Runnable {
    private final App bot;

    public ParsingExchange(App bot) {
        this.bot = bot;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bot.execute(new SendMessage("42", "Текст сообщения"));
        } catch (TelegramApiException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы это заработало, класс `App` должен наследоваться от `TelegramLongPollingBot` или `TelegramWebhookBot`, чтобы на нем был определен метод `execute`.

Comment: да, все верно, спасибо